# SQL Converter minutos para hora:minuto:segundos

Tags: sql, oracle, datetime, conversão

Como converter um valor em minutos no oracle para o formato hora:minutos:segundos?

Answer (score 5):

Converte minutos para o formato hour:min:sec , por exemplo 1000 minutos convertidos ficaria 16:40:00

```
SELECT 
   TO_CHAR(TRUNC((MINUTES * 60) / 3600), 'FM9900') || ':' ||
   TO_CHAR(TRUNC(MOD((MINUTES * 60), 3600) / 60), 'FM00') || ':' ||
   TO_CHAR(MOD((MINUTES * 60), 60), 'FM00') AS MIN_TO_HOUR FROM DUAL
```

Comment: Interessante, fiz a aplicação em uma função referente a diferença em Horas, Minutos e Segundos de uma data e outra. Vlw